# Primefaces file upload auto="true": preserve images preview

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, param

Have `Primefaces` [file-upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf) component with `auto="true"` param:

```
...
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadFileBean.upload}" mode="advanced" auto="true"/>  
...
```

When `auto="true"`,that after image been uploaded,preview of image disappeared.

Is it possible,that uploaded images(files) preview remained in the list,like it works,when `auto="false"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps you should perform:

**1.** add container for images preview with particular id,let it be `info`
**2.** add parameter `update="info"` into `p:fileUpload`  tag
**3.** ovverride styles of container that is standardly displayed by `Primefaces` engine with `CSS` styles like `display:none`,in particular, this one:

```
.files{
    display:none;
}
```